# Animating a full-width SVG with background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

This has been quite challenging. I've got the main functionality I want working now in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/marc_havas/pen/xEVjZL). The SVG is mainly split up in 3 sections where the middle section slides away from the others when you click the "Find Out More" button.

My main problem is that I need it to be the full viewport of the browser. I cannot seem to resize to match any screen size and I need to use the SVG as an inline element so that I can do the animation.

My code (identical to the Pen above) is listed below:

HTML

```
<div class="home-overlay">
    <svg width="100vw" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 1440 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>Desktop HD</title>
        <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
                <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465281508053-aee07fc08957" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon id="lines-left" fill="url(#image)" points="0 0 310 0 400 1024 0 1024"></polygon>
        <polygon id="lines-right" fill="url(#image)" points="1040 0 1440 0 1440 1024 1130 1024"></polygon>
        <polygon id="lines-center" class="lines-center" fill="url(#image)" points="310 0 1040 0 1130 1024 400 1024"></polygon>
        <polygon id="lines-center-image" class="lines-center" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" points="310 0 1040 0 1130 1024 400 1024"></polygon>

    </svg>

    <button id="clear_overlay">Find out more</button>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.home-overlay {
z-index: 9999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
// position: fixed;
display: block;

&.clearitout {

    svg {
        polygon#lines-left {
            transform: translate(91px, 1024px);
            transition: transform 1s ease;
        }

        polygon#lines-right {
            transform: translate(91px, 1024px);
            transition: transform 1s ease;
        }

        polygon.lines-center {
            transform: translate(-91px, -1024px);
            transition: transform 1s ease;
        }
    }

}

button#clear_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 35%;
}
```

}

jQuery

```
$('#clear_overlay').on('click', function(){
 $('.home-overlay').addClass('clearitout');
 $('.home-overlay').fadeOut(800);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you remove the width and height of the SVG?

```js
jQuery('#clear_overlay').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('.home-overlay').addClass('clearitout');
  jQuery('.home-overlay').fadeOut(800);
});
```

```css
.home-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  &.clearitout {
    svg {
      polygon#lines-left {
        transform: translate(91px, 1024px);
        transition: transform 1s ease;
      }
      polygon#lines-right {
        transform: translate(91px, 1024px);
        transition: transform 1s ease;
      }
      polygon.lines-center {
        transform: translate(-91px, -1024px);
        transition: transform 1s ease;
      }
    }
  }
}
button#clear_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 35%;
}
svg {
  width: 100%
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-overlay">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Desktop HD</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
      <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
        <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465281508053-aee07fc08957" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon id="lines-left" fill="url(#image)" points="0 0 310 0 400 1024 0 1024"></polygon>
    <polygon id="lines-right" fill="url(#image)" points="1040 0 1440 0 1440 1024 1130 1024"></polygon>
    <polygon id="lines-center" class="lines-center" fill="url(#image)" points="310 0 1040 0 1130 1024 400 1024"></polygon>
    <polygon id="lines-center-image" class="lines-center" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" points="310 0 1040 0 1130 1024 400 1024"></polygon>

  </svg>


</div>

<button id="clear_overlay">Find out more</button>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxrdj

Comment: Problem is, it doesn't ever fully fit the full width of the parent container/viewport. Plus it becomes incredibly long. I need it to literally be a snug fit on all edges.

Comment: It doesn't? Did you reset all default paddings/margins?

Comment: Inspect the element on the pen you made and you'll see there's a tiny margin around it that I cannot account for. The image seems to sit centred inside of the polygons. It fits in width but not in height.

Comment: That's a margin on the body coming from the browser's default styles. I've overridden it and hidden the overflow of the image. The leftover whitespace at the top is due to where you have placed the image inside your svg.

Comment: You have literally saved my life. Thank you. I spent 2 full days trying to figure it out, ignored it for a month and just gave up.

Comment: Happy to help, Marc. Don't give up, keep going!

Comment: And feel free to accept this answer if it saved your life ;)